# AngularJS $http request to Coursera's REST API. Cross-origin denied although public key is not required

Tags: ajax, rest, cors, angular-http, coursera-api

Coursera API documentation:
    https://tech.coursera.org/app-platform/catalog/

I tried to make a simple GET call to the api:

- https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1

Like This:

```
$scope.courseraSearch = function(query){


    var courseraAPIUrl = 'https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1?q=search&query=Machine+Learning';

    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: courseraAPIUrl
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      console.log(response);
      for(i in response.data.elements){
        $scope.courseraResults.push(response.data.elements[i]);
      }
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
    });
  }
```

but I always get CORS error or "Refused to execute script from '*' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled." error.

I tried using cors.io as proxy:

```
$scope.courseraSearch = function(query){

    //https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1?q=search&query=Calculus
    var courseraAPIUrl = 'http://cors.io/?u=https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1?q=search&query=Machine+Learning';

    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: courseraAPIUrl
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      console.log(response);
      for(i in response.data.elements){
        $scope.courseraResults.push(response.data.elements[i]);
      }
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
    });
  }
```

But doing so, I can't seem to pass in any parameters (when I pass in "Machine Learning" query, it returns normal query as if I didn't put any search term in)

I've already tried jsonp as well...

Comment: Does Coursera even offer a JSONP option? If not, why would you even bother trying it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `cors.io`, you should probably make sure the parameters are encoded correctly. Easiest way to do this is use the `params` HTTP config property

```
$http.get('http://cors.io/', {
    params: {
        u: 'https://api.coursera.org/api/courses.v1?q=search&query=Machine+Learning'
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked.

Could use explain what the "u" parameter does?

Comment: @Sam.E That's the `u` query parameter in `http://cors.io/?u=...`. URL parameters need to be [encoded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) which is what Angular does to the `params` object when constructing the request.